# Reducing a rectangular matrix of large rationals to small rationals

Tags: matrices, number-theory

I have a large matrix (~1000 by ~2000), whose entries are purely rational numbers, typically involving large fractions, that is numbers (much) larger than 10^8 in denominator/numerator. The original problem strongly suggests that by multiplying, adding and subtracting rows one can reach a form which is "simple". By this I mean:

1) only a small number of entries in each row are non-zero (say not more 20 or so)

2) the entries are all small integer fractions (numbers less than ~10^2 in denominator/numerator)

I would be interested in an algorithm that produces this form. Note that I'm **not** asking for row-reducing: for a non-square matrix like the one I have, this will only simplify a 1000 columns, but not the remaining 1000, whose entries are really very ugly rational numbers in general.

In a way, I want to minimize the "information content" of the matrix.